# Can not click on link in jquery animated div?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, mouseover, animated

I'm having this problem :

I have some divs wich are animated with jquery, and I need some links in them.
I put the links in normal "html a href's"..

Is there a way to make this possible?
I've been searching the internet for two days now, and even asked a teacher webdesign, but we can not find anything helpfull.

This is the site I'm working on :

http://designchitchat.be/bart/vuurdood-site/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: come on. Provide some code...

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? I can't see any link in the page you provided...

Comment: You need to explain your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to test if the target is an "a" element or not

I made an jsfiddle, you can test the link i put in "Links" box

http://jsfiddle.net/7QJPH/5/

You can also test this javascript, it's only work with the "links" box, you have to duplicate for other parts

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#kogelclip').draggable();
    $('#vulpen').draggable();
    $('#bio').toggle(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            top: '+=390'
        }, {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'swing'
        });

    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            top: '-=390'
        }, {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'swing'
        });
    });



    $('#discografie').toggle(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '+=560'
        }, {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'swing'
        });

    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '-=560'
        }, {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'swing'
        });
    });
    $('#links').toggle(function(event) {
        if (!$(event.target).is('a')) {

            $(this).animate({
                right: '+=560'
            }, {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'swing'
            });

        } else {
            document.location.href = $(event.target).attr('href');
        }
    }, function(event) {
        if (!$(event.target).is('a')) {
            $(this).animate({
                right: '-=560'
            }, {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'swing'
            });
        } else {
            document.location.href = $(event.target).attr('href');
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: Thanks!
This works perfectly!

Only, when I click on the link and then go back in the browser (to my site), the link-div is like he was when I left the page (folded out) and when I click on it, it folds out again..

Comment: (Only in Chrome this doesn't happen)
Is there a way to make my site refresh when people arrive on it by going back in their browser?
So it will reset to the normal state every visit?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood. You may do this way.

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px">
 <a href="http://somesite.com" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;height:100%"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sasha, I got what he wanted. He has provided some information on 'DISCOGRAFIE' and 'BIO' boards which are sliding after on click due to animation effect of jquery. I think, he wanted to put links on these block. but After clicking, animation is being triggered rather than invoking hyperlink click event.

This can be achieved by  onHover effect for all your required links. As onClick event is being used by animation block.
To get this, Just add below code inside document.ready of jQuery.

```
$("a").hover(function(){
      var link=$(this).attr('href');
      location.redirect(link);
});
```